# How to check if cell is empty in appscript?

Tags: google-apps-script

```
    function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl ('doc url');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("new project")
  var v1 = sheet.getLastRow()
  Logger.log(v1);
  var v2 = sheet.getLastColumn()
  Logger.log(v2);
  var data = sheet.getRange(2,1, v1, v2).getValues()
  Logger.log(data);
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; ++i) 
  {
    n=i+1
    Logger.log(i);
    var data1 = sheet.getRange(n,1,1,13).getValues()
    Logger.log(data1);
    var s= s.getRange(1,9)
  }
}
```

basicaly i want check if cell s is empty, what should i write, i tried  different methods but nothing worked, thanks in advance

Comment: `if (data[i][j] == '')`  or if range for that cell `isEmpty()` are a couple of ways.

Answer (score 2):

### Answer

*Use the method [isBlank](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#isblank) in a range.*

### Explanation

The method `isBlank` can be applied to an individual cell or a range of cells. It returns `true` only if all the cells in the range are blank or empty.

### Test

Having the following range:

[image]

And applying this code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  console.log('A1 -> '+ss.getRange('A1').isBlank())
  console.log('A2 -> '+ss.getRange('A2').isBlank())
  console.log('B1:B2 -> '+ss.getRange('B1:B2').isBlank())
  console.log('C1:C2 -> '+ss.getRange('C1:C2').isBlank())
}
```

We obtain:

```
5:36:45 PM  Info    A1 -> true
5:36:45 PM  Info    A2 -> false
5:36:45 PM  Info    B1:B2 -> true
5:36:45 PM  Info    C1:C2 -> false
```

### Reference

- [Range.isBlank](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#isblank)

Answer (score 1):

If you get the value from a cell that's empty, it'll always be a string.

With that in mind, you can do the following to check if column S is empty for any given row.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('sheet url');
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('sheet name');
  const data = sheet.getRange(2,1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  let counter = 2;
  for (const row of data) {
    if (row[18] == '') {
      console.log(`S in row ${counter} is empty`)
    }
    counter++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this functionality

```
    //get the values of sheet into a variable
    
     var data = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    
    //get the range of cells to counter variable which you need to check 
    
        var counter = sheet.getRange(1, 4).getValue();
              
         for(var i=counter;i< data.length-1;i++)
         {
           if(data[i][1]==="")
           {
             //do your logic here
           }
        }
```

Comment: i found your method most usefull in a way that i want to do it, however it doesent work for me, mb i cant figure it out, for a context i use first row for descriptions, this is why i use varriable n, and then use data from second, however there is a chance that from a 9 column there will be no data in a row, this is why i want to check through cycle and write it separate (for now in logger) from other data in a row